# Calculate period expires date in second or minutes or hours or days

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to create a method it returns string and (calculate the period expires days) differences between expires date and current date.

- if the differences is less than 1 minutes i will return in second ex: 8 seconds
- if the differences is less than 1 hours i will return in minutes ex: 28 minutes
- if the differences is less than 24 (a day) hours i will return in hours ex: 7 hours
- default if not matches any case I will return days ex: 3 days

what I have already tried is

```
(item.EndDate- DateTime.Today).Days
```

But is does not work when the difference less than 24 hours it will return 0.

Can you give me suggestion?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please use the edit lint to include the code you've tried in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your expiration time starting by biggest value (which in your question it's a day). First write your method like below:

```
public static string CalculateExpirationTime(DateTime expiryDate)
{
    var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
    var dateDifference = (expiryDate - currentDate);

    if (dateDifference.Days >= 1)
        return $"{ dateDifference.Days } day(s) remained";
    else if (dateDifference.Hours >= 1)
        return $"{ dateDifference.Hours } hour(s) remained";
    else if (dateDifference.Minutes >= 1)
        return $"{ dateDifference.Minutes } minute(s) remained";
    else if (dateDifference.TotalSeconds >= 1)
        return $"{ dateDifference.Seconds } second(s) remained";

    return "Expired!";
}
```

And then call it this way:

```
string status = CalculateExpirationTime(item.EndDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question

> when the difference less than 24 hours it will return 0 can you give me suggestion?

You can use [`TotalDays`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totaldays?view=netframework-4.8);

```
double ds = ((d1-d2).TotalDays;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime biggerDate;  // pretend it has some valid value
DateTime smallDate;  //     ditto

TimeSpan datesDiff = biggerDate - smallDate;  // assume a positive diff.

if (dateDiff.TotalMinutes < 1) {return new TimeSpan(0,0,0,8);} else
if (dateDiff.TotalHours < 1)   {return new TimeSpan(0,0,28);} else
if (dateDiff.TotalDays < 1)    {return new TimeSpan(0,7,0);} else
return new TimeSpan(3,0,0);
```

------------- or ? --------------

```
if (dateDiff.TotalMinutes < 1) {return dateDiff.TotalSeconds;} else
if (dateDiff.TotalHours < 1)   {return dateDiff.TotalMinutes;} else
if (dateDiff.TotalDays < 1)    {return dateDiff.TotalHours} else
return dateDiff.TotalDays;
```

-